How to simulate transaction at specific slot
Given a connection and a VersionedTransaction I can simulate the tx using web3js like so:
await connection.simulateTransaction(tx, config)

here config is of type SimulateTransactionConfig:
type SimulateTransactionConfig = {
    /** Optional parameter used to enable signature verification before simulation */
    sigVerify?: boolean;
    /** Optional parameter used to replace the simulated transaction's recent blockhash with the latest blockhash */
    replaceRecentBlockhash?: boolean;
    /** Optional parameter used to set the commitment level when selecting the latest block */
    commitment?: Commitment;
    /** Optional parameter used to specify a list of base58-encoded account addresses to return post simulation state for */
    accounts?: {
        /** The encoding of the returned account's data */
        encoding: 'base64';
        addresses: string[];
    };
    /** Optional parameter used to specify the minimum block slot that can be used for simulation */
    minContextSlot?: number;
    /** Optional parameter used to include inner instructions in the simulation */
    innerInstructions?: boolean;
};

I'm wondering if there's a way to simulate the transaction at a specific slot in the past? My understanding is that minContextSlot is only to make sure that the node is up to date to at least such slot, but would not make the simulation at that slot.

You can only simulate in the past using the three different commitment levels -- finalized is ~32 slots back, confirmed is ~1 slot back confirmed by consensus, and processed is what was immediately processed by the node that processes the request.
